# Configure Jetty in Spring Boot using usual Jetty XML

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

Is there a simple way to use (or reuse) external Jetty configuration files to configure an embedded Jetty web container with Spring Boot.

Programmatic configuration to change only the listening port for example is acceptable, but a full configuration including multiple connectors, thread pools, etc. seems to be better suited with usual Jetty files.

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There's no support in Spring Boot for configuring Jetty via XML. You can use `application.properties` for simpler cases or programmatic configuration for things that are more complex.

Boot's Tomcat integration is a little bit ahead of its Jetty integration in terms of what you can configure via `application.properties`. For example, you can configure Tomcat's thread pool. If you'd like to see some improvements to the Jetty integration then please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new), or, even better, a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for that answer even if it does not meet all of my needs.
For now, I'll try to configure basics settings using a bit of code and some properties, and I'll try to express a request to improve Jetty's configuration in Spring Boot.
Regards.